# duplicate pages due to trailing slash

Tags: .htaccess, seo, duplicates

Some of my pages are duplicate due to trailing slash problem.
E.g `socktail.com/shop` and `socktail.com/shop/` are duplicate and accessible.
Please let me know how to fix this problem. I am new to web technologies and don't even know that my .htaccess file is ok or not.
Following is the content of my .htaccess,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|javascript|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(([a-z0-9_]+\.)?socktail\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .? {REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that almost all requests are handled by your index.php file. You'll either need to redirect all requests with a trailing slash to a request without a trailing slash, or you'll need to do it the other way around.

```
#Remove all trailing slashes
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Or...

```
#Make sure all requests end with one
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/
```

And add that rule after `RewriteBase`, but before your first `RewriteRule`/`RewriteCond`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a rule for removal of trailing slash with 301. Keep you all rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

# existing rule
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|javascript|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```